# possible to use jquery dialog with asp.net user control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to open a user control in a jquery dialog popup but when I do, none of the server side events fire, and I'm guessing the UpdatePanels will also be disabled.

Anyone come across this before and is there a way around this to ensure that the user control works as expected?

This is the code I have for it.  The user control itself is an image uploader and has three update panels, and a number of buttons/imagebuttons with server side click events.

```
<a href="#" id="imgDialog">Open Gallery</a>  
<div id="ImagePopup" style="display:none">
    <uc1:ImageGallery ID="ImageGallery1" ImageSectionID="1" runat="server" />    
</div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#imgDialog").click(, function (e) {
            $('#ImagePopup').dialog({
                bgiframe: true,
                modal: true,
                show: ("slide", { direction: "down" }, 200),
                hide: ("slide", { direction: "up" }, 200),
                showOpt: { direction: 'up' },
                width: 700,
                close: function (event, ui) {
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm happy to move the control to an aspx page and use an iframe if necessary, but wanted to check first before I do.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to append dialog to the Form in order for the events to fire. Do it by adding the appendTo line as in the following code:

```
$("#imgDialog").click(, function (e) {
            $('#ImagePopup').dialog({
                bgiframe: true,
                ...........
                close: function (event, ui) {
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#ImagePopup').parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
        });
```

I have used Juery UI dialog with server controls, including controls for file uploading. I assure you it is possible.

I'm not sure but maybe your dialog will open only once. If that happen, try defining the close function like:

```
close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).remove();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you put the server controls in the jQuery popup it will remove the controls from the `form runat="server"` and place it outside the form..

So because your controls are not inside the `form runat="server"` the server side events will not fire.

One workaround for this kind of issues is explicitly clone the wrapper after the usercontrol is loaded and append it to the `form runat="server"` . This should solve your problem..

You can check this with Firebug or any developer tools that the popup will be outside the form..

Comment: Yes you're spot on - it has been created outside the form.  How would I explicity clone the wrapper?

Comment: I used clone which is a wrong word here .. Select the modalpopup and append it inside the form..

Comment: $('#mdpopup').appendTo('form')